# Creating application insights with azure cli

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-cli

I would like to create application insights using AZURE CLI. I can't find any documentation on this topic. Is it possible?

Comment: Take a look here https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/5543#issuecomment-365001620

Comment: Seems nice, I will try it

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The link provided by Rohit works

```
az resource create \
    --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP \
    --resource-type "Microsoft.Insights/components" \
    --name $NAMESPACE_PREFIX-appinsights \
    --location $PRIMARY_LOCATION \
    --properties '{"Application_Type":"web"}'
```

https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/5543#issuecomment-365001620

Comment: Does not work on Windows: `Error parsing JSON. '{Application_Type:web}' `. The fix is `--properties "{\"Application_Type\":\"web\"}"`

Answer (score 5):

The [az monitor app-insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/application-insights/monitor/app-insights/component?view=azure-cli-latest#ext-application-insights-az-monitor-app-insights-component-create) component provide commands for creating, inspecting modifying, and deleting application insights components from the command line.

Comment: But don't forgot to install the AZ/CLI extensions with `az extension add --name application-insights` or the sub-command won't be available.

Answer (score 3):

Use: [az monitor app-insights component create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/application-insights/monitor/app-insights/component?view=azure-cli-latest#ext_application_insights_az_monitor_app_insights_component_create)

```
az monitor app-insights component create --app
                                         --location
                                         --resource-group
                                         [--application-type]
                                         [--ingestion-access {Disabled, Enabled}]
                                         [--kind]
                                         [--query-access {Disabled, Enabled}]
                                         [--retention-time]
                                         [--tags]
                                         [--workspace]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to associate the generated instrumentation key with another resource, such as a function app, you can use `grep` and `xargs` as follows:

```
# Creates insights component for monitoring. Note generated instrumentation key
# is set in function app.
az resource create \
    --resource-group ${RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME} \
    --resource-type "Microsoft.Insights/components" \
    --name ${FUNCTION_APP_NAME} \
    --location ${LOCATION} \
    --properties '{"Application_Type":"web"}' \
| grep -Po "\"InstrumentationKey\": \K\".*\"" \
| xargs -I % az functionapp config appsettings set \
    --name ${FUNCTION_APP_NAME} \
    --resource-group ${RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME} \
    --settings "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY = %"
```

Answer (score 0):

Application Insights is an extensible Application Performance Management (APM) service for web developers on multiple platforms. You can use it to monitor your live web application. You can get more details about [Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-overview?toc=/azure/azure-monitor/toc.json).

It belongs to the Azure Monitor. You can find appropriate CLI command from [`az monitor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/monitor?view=azure-cli-latest). Hope this will be helpful.